# Android method does not execute httppost request

Tags: android, exception, post, httpresponse

I have to do an http post for get a token which will give me permissions for use my app.
The method(obtieneToken) which obtains this token its into the Asyntask Class beside to another methods. This method is called from another class no asynchronous which is called from the App activity.
When my function arrives to the httpClient.execute(post) the index goes to the exception.
I compared my app versus my web application and the web application works well. The next step was capture with Wireshark and... When i execute my app, my wlan interface does not receive any request from the app. Which can be the problem?
Here is the code:

```
public class ObtencionDatosUsuario extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Boolean> {


protected static User obtieneDatos(String url, String aut) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet del = new HttpGet(url);// Se obtienen
                                                            // los datos de
                                                            // la url del
                                                            // usuario
    del.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    del.setHeader("X-Auth-Token",aut);// contenidoToken es el string que se obtiene de la respuesta del token
    User usuario = new User();
    try {
        HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(del);
        StatusLine estatus = resp.getStatusLine();
        if (estatus.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            InputStream is= null;
            is = resp.getEntity().getContent();
            usuario =(User) HalUnmarshaller.unmarshal(is, User.class);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error");
            usuario= null;
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("ServicioRest", "Error!", ex);
    }
    return usuario;
}

protected static List<User> obtieneAmigos(String url, String aut) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet del = new HttpGet(url);// Se obtienen los datos de la url del
                                    // usuario
    del.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    del.setHeader("X-Auth-Token", aut);
    List<User> friends = null;
        HttpResponse resp;
        try {
            resp = httpClient.execute(del);
            StatusLine estatus = resp.getStatusLine();
            if(estatus.getStatusCode()==200){
                InputStream is= null;
                is = resp.getEntity().getContent();
                friends= (List<User>) HalUnmarshaller.unmarshal(is, User.class);
                return friends;
            }else{
                friends= null;
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return friends;
}

protected static List<GroupEvent> obtieneEventos(String url, String aut) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet del = new HttpGet(url); // Se obtienen los datos de la url del usuario
    del.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    del.setHeader("X-Auth-Token",aut);
    List<GroupEvent> eventos = null;
        HttpResponse resp;
        try {
            resp = httpClient.execute(del);
            StatusLine estatus = resp.getStatusLine();
            if(estatus.getStatusCode() == 200){
                InputStream is= null;
                is= resp.getEntity().getContent();
                eventos = (List<GroupEvent>) HalUnmarshaller.unmarshal(is, GroupEvent.class);

            }else{
                eventos= null;
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return eventos;

}
//getToken 
protected static AuthToken obtieneToken(String nombre, String clave, String url){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AuthToken token= new AuthToken();
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);// Solicitud token
    int code;
    String aut=nombre+":"+clave;
    String conectionValue;
    String codificada= Base64.encodeToString(aut.getBytes(), 0);
    String coded= codificada.replace("\n", "");
    System.out.println("nombre:clave= "+aut+" codificado es= "+coded);
    post.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+coded);
    try {
        HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(post);//Genera una excepcion 
        InputStream is= resp.getEntity().getContent();
        if((code=resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode())!=200){
            token.setAuthToken("0");


        }else{
        token= (AuthToken) HalUnmarshaller.unmarshal(is, AuthToken.class);
        System.out.println("Token recibido en obtencion: "+ token);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {//Excepcion lanzad a por el post
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    return token;
}
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

This is the class which contains the Callers to the async methods:

```
public class ObtieneRecursos {
static String ip= "192.168.0.15";
public static User obtieneDatosUsuario(String aut, String who){
    //Peticion get a /users/:id
    String url= "http://"+ip+":8080/api/users/"+who;
    User usuario= new User();
    usuario= ObtencionDatosUsuario.obtieneDatos(url,aut);

    return usuario;
}
public static AuthToken obtieneTokenMe(String nombre, String clave){
    String url= "http://"+ip+":8080/api/auth-tokens/";
    AuthToken token= new AuthToken();
    token= ObtencionDatosUsuario.obtieneToken(nombre, clave, url);
    return token;
   }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Edit: Log

```
03-11 13:31:39.272: I/ViewRootImpl(522): ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch Down
03-11 13:31:39.312: I/ViewRootImpl(522): ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch UP
03-11 13:31:46.472: I/System.out(522): Recibido mik.xx@gmail.com|xx
03-11 13:31:46.562: I/System.out(522): nombre:clave= mik.xx@gmail.com:xx codificado es= bWlrLmNvcmN1ZXJhQGdtYWlsLmNvbTpjb3JjdWVyYTkx

03-11 13:31:48.632: E/DataScheduler(522): isDataSchedulerEnabled():false

03-11 13:31:48.632: W/System.err(522): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-11 13:31:48.642: W/System.err(522):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1148)
03-11 13:31:48.642: W/System.err(522):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
03-11 13:31:48.642: W/System.err(522):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:176)
03-11 13:31:48.642: W/System.err(522):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:128)
03-11 13:31:48.642: W/System.err(522):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-11 13:31:48.642: W/System.err(522):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
03-11 13:31:48.642: W/System.err(522):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:833)
03-11 13:31:48.642: W/System.err(522):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
03-11 13:31:48.642: W/System.err(522):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
03-11 13:31:48.642: W/System.err(522):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-11 13:31:48.642: W/System.err(522):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-11 13:31:48.642: W/System.err(522):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
03-11 13:31:48.642: W/System.err(522):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-11 13:31:48.642: W/System.err(522):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-11 13:31:48.642: W/System.err(522):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-11 13:31:48.642: W/System.err(522):  at com.example.modelo.ObtencionDatosUsuario.obtieneToken(ObtencionDatosUsuario.java:144)
03-11 13:31:48.642: W/System.err(522):  at com.example.modelo.ObtieneRecursos.obtieneTokenMe(ObtieneRecursos.java:27)
03-11 13:31:48.652: W/System.err(522):  at com.example.pestanasholacampus.InitActivity.compruebaUsuario(InitActivity.java:122)
03-11 13:31:48.652: W/System.err(522):  at com.example.pestanasholacampus.InitActivity$2.onClick(InitActivity.java:68)
03-11 13:31:48.652: W/System.err(522):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
03-11 13:31:48.652: W/System.err(522):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
03-11 13:31:48.652: W/System.err(522):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-11 13:31:48.652: W/System.err(522):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-11 13:31:48.652: W/System.err(522):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-11 13:31:48.652: W/System.err(522):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
03-11 13:31:48.652: W/System.err(522):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 13:31:48.652: W/System.err(522):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-11 13:31:48.652: W/System.err(522):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
03-11 13:31:48.652: W/System.err(522):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
03-11 13:31:48.652: W/System.err(522):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit 2: Now i have the code in doInBackground methods called from normal class:

```
public class ObtencionTokenUsuario extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, AuthToken> {

@Override
protected AuthToken doInBackground(String... datos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AuthToken token= new AuthToken();
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(datos[2]);// Solicitud token
            int code;
            String aut=datos[0]+":"+datos[1];
            String conectionValue;
            String codificada= Base64.encodeToString(aut.getBytes(), 0);
            String coded= codificada.replace("\n", "");
            System.out.println("nombre:clave= "+aut+" codificado es= "+coded);
            post.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            post.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+coded);
            try {
                HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(post);//Genera una excepcion 
                InputStream is= resp.getEntity().getContent();
                if((code=resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode())!=200){
                    token.setAuthToken("0");


                }else{
                token= (AuthToken) HalUnmarshaller.unmarshal(is, AuthToken.class);
                System.out.println("Token recibido en obtencion: "+ token);
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {//Excepcion lanzad a por el post
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }

            return token;
}
```

}

And the class:

```
public class ObtieneRecursos{
public static AuthToken obtieneTokenMe(String nombre, String clave){
    String url= "http://"+ip+":8080/api/auth-tokens/";
    String[] params= new String[3];
    params[0]=nombre;
    params[1]=clave;
    params[2]=url;
    System.out.println("nombre = "+params[0]);
    System.out.println("clave = "+params[1]);
    System.out.println("url = "+params[2]);
    AuthToken token= new AuthToken();
    ObtencionTokenUsuario du= new ObtencionTokenUsuario();
    token=du.doInBackground(params);
    return token;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you add internet permission into manifest file  ? I still make this mistake ))

Comment: Yes, i have them. ^^ this line: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Can you post your error log ? it may help to understand mistake.

Comment: have you ever read the docu of asynctask, you're doing nothing in the doInBackground

Comment: Need i one asynchronous class for each method http method?

Comment: Oh, how can i miss this. When you call .execute method you run doInBackground in you AsyncTask class. And get result from postExecute(). Read docu http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: So, i need one async class with doInBackground and onPostExecute for each request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: I have modified the code to run all in background but it is the same exception NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was on HttpPost, which received a String and not an URI.